# Alfresco Get Attachments from external IMAP Email

Tags: email, localhost, imap, alfresco

Hello I want to ask if it is possible to get email attachments from en external email account or does someone know how I send emails to a localhost server?

I am using Alfresco on Mac OSX and it is the community version 4.2.c

Best regards
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video that explains how to configure inbound email for Alfresco Community Edition:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p17GkHsLdmc

You can also refer to the official docs for Community Edition at http://docs.alfresco.com/community/index.jsp

Comment: I've seen this and it explains how to configure if your server where Alfresco runs has an address but I can't send an email to my localhost!

Comment: I'm having a hard time determining what, specifically, you are having a problem with.

Comment: I have alfreco installed on localhost and I want to send an attachmwnt mail to it... and I don't have a bloody clue what host i have to insert... my private email domain or localhost or what?

Comment: Here's what I do: In my /etc/hosts I have an entry for 127.0.0.1 that says "jpotts.alfresco-laptop.com". Then, in my inbound SMTP configuration in alfresco-global.properties I set my email.server.domain to jpotts.alfresco-laptop.com and my email server port to 1025. I then fire up my email client and configure its outbound SMTP server to that domain and 1025. If you want to route mail from some other machine to this machine, that's a different story, but this works for local testing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it made some things clearer.... 
But the thing I want is that I can send mails to a globally accessible email address and copy the attachments into a folder

Comment: If you can get it to work locally then getting it to work from other servers is a matter of networking, DNS entries, and MX records (I assume). It isn't Alfresco-specific.